# Write a list objects in JSON using Python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am trying to output the following JSON from my python (2.7) script:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1002-00001",
    "name": "Name 1"
  },
  {
    "id": "1002-00002",
    "display": "Name 2"
  },
]
```

What data structure in Python will output this when using `json.dumps`?
The outermost item is a python list, but what should be the type of items inside the list? It looks like a dictionary with no keys?

Comment: With no keys? What are 'id' & 'name' then?

Comment: AFAIK a list of dictionaries `{"id": idvalue, "name":namevalue}` will do

Comment: This is already a perfectly valid Python datastructure.

Comment: Okay I am confused. What are the types of the individual elements of {"id": idvalue, "name":namevalue}. There are two key value pairs in that. Maybe I have been staring at the code too long.

Comment: `repr(data).replace("'",'"') == json.dumps(data))` gives me True and since you wrote it with double quotes you have written a data structure that is valid in both.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this clarifies the notes in comments that are not clear for you. It's achieved by appending (in this case small) dictionaries into a list.

```
import json

#Added an extra entry with an integer type. Doesn't have to be string.
full_list = [['1002-00001', 'Name 1'],
            ['1002-00002', 'Name 2'],
            ['1002-00003', 2]]

output_list = []            
for item in full_list:
    sub_dict = {}
    sub_dict['id'] = item[0] # key-value pair defined
    sub_dict['name'] = item[1]
    output_list.append(sub_dict) # Just put the mini dictionary into a list

# See Python data structure
print output_list

# Specifically using json.dumps as requested in question.
# Automatically adds double quotes to strings for json formatting in printed 
# output but keeps ints (unquoted)
json_object = json.dumps(output_list)
print json_object 

# Writing to a file
with open('SO_jsonout.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(output_list, outfile)

# What I think you are confused about with the "keys" is achieved with an 
# outer dictionary (but isn't necessary to make a valid data structure, just
# one that you might be more used to seeing)
outer_dict = {}
outer_dict['so_called_missing_key'] = output_list
print outer_dict
```